# Tiled - supporting different ios devices

Tags: ios, editor, tiled

I would like to know, how do you support different screen sizes when using Tiled with Spritekit?

Do you design you levels in separate .tmx files for each device? For example:

ipad-nonretina-level-1.tmx (normal tile size),
ipad-retina-level-1.tmx (doubled tile size),

and so on. Or there is some way to use one .tmx  file(for each level) and dynamically load a tileset based on detected device, precisely based on the scale factor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently answered this question here:

http://forum.mapeditor.org/t/using-tilesets-across-multiple-ios-devices/132

Essentially, to avoid juggling around multiple map files this is something you should aim to solve in your game engine.

If this is not possible for whatever reason (for example because you're using a library for loading the TMX file which makes this unachievable), you'll probably want to write a small script that you can apply on the map file to generate the versions for other resolutions.

I'm sorry but I can't provide any concrete source code for SpriteKit.